# DataGridView add row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NXZG.png)I am trying to add rows to DataGridView which I suceeded but I have one column unbounded where some math take place.
I want sum of that column below it.

Note: `Cell(10)` is the one unbounded. In this case I get an error:

> Column does not exist

(obviously, it is not in datatable). Here is my code:

```
Public Sub PrintData()
    PrintSQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Cisnik WHERE Datum = '" & 
                       CDate(LB2.Text).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") & "'; ")
    If PrintSQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub
    DGV3Print.DataSource = PrintSQL.DBDT

    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DGV3Print.Rows
        r.Cells(10).Value = (r.Cells(1).Value - r.Cells(2).Value - r.Cells(4).Value - r.Cells(6).Value)
        tb = tb + r.Cells(10).Value
    Next

    Dim myrow = PrintSQL.DBDT.NewRow
    myrow(0) = "CELKEM"
    myrow(10) = tb
    PrintSQL.DBDT.Rows.Add(myrow)
End Sub
```

I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Can you post an Image of your datagridview? Use the edit button to add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Datum column really stored in the database as a string? You really shouldn't be concatenating strings to build an SQL query. Learn to use parameters. Why take a string, convert it to a Date then back to a string? To solve your problem simply let the database do the work. This just demonstrates the pattern to use. Then bind to your grid.

```
Dim s = "Select Num1, Num2, Num3, Num1 + Num2 + Num3 As Total From Numbers;"
```

Comment: The problemi is in addrow section. Above everything works fine.

Comment: Line myrow(0) = "Celkem"  adds a cell with that text (works well)  and myrow(10) should add variable to cell at 10th place. The variable has the value but refuses to write to that cell because  Datatable does not have cell no. 10. Cell (10) is unbounded. Visually the row is added to that cell but no value is written. Line   myrow(10) =  tb generates the error.

Comment: If you follow my advice and bind the resulting data table to the DataGridView, you will have your total column and it will be filled in with the total.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way: It may be amateurish because I am total beginer but it actualy works in way I need. The code is:

```
 Dim myrow = PrintSQL.DBDT.NewRow
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DGV3Print.Rows.Count - 1
    DGV3Print.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "CELKEM"
    DGV3Print.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = tb
    PrintSQL.DBDT.Rows.Add(myrow)
```

Anyway thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to add a row to a DataGridView is:

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add({Data1,Data2})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a row to a DateGridView, see the example below.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_database.htm

I'm know you can sum data points in a DataGridView, but I haven't done this for a very long time.  Something like this should be pretty close...

```
Dim sum As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
    sum = sum + dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
Next

textBoxSum.Text = sum.ToString()
```